# How to append column value in alias as column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like below:

```
select Json_Query((
    select Id,
    Name
    from employeeTable
    inner join ....
    )) as 'employeeTable_EmployeeID_' + convert(varchar(20) as Id)
```

I am getting error on **+** saying "`Incorrect syntax`".

I am trying to generate a key in the json using "`Table Name`" and the "`EmployeeId`" like below:

Expected Output :

```
employeeTable_EmployeeID_100
```

How do I do that?

Can someone please help?

**Update:**

I am trying to generate a json structure on same table and column for different employees like below:

```
select Json_Query((
    select Id,
    Name
    from employeeTable where Id = 1 For JSON auto, Include_NULL_VALUES
    )) as 'employeeTable'
    ,
    select Json_Query((
    select Id,
    Name
    from employeeTable where Id = 2 For JSON auto, Include_NULL_VALUES
    )) as 'employeeTable' For JSON path, Root('Report_100')
```

When I am trying to run above query, its throwing exception saying duplicate key "employeeTable" that is why I am trying to append Employee ID in the key.

Comment: You cannot use an expression for an alias, it must be a literal. If you "have" to make it dynamic, you'd had to use dynamic SQL. Seems like a possible [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) to me

Comment: @ThomA Is there anyway to generate an alias using the primary key value?

Comment: I think you need to explain what your *real* goal is here. As mentioned, this smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: `generate an alias using the primary key value` -> why, and how do you expect a column to have different names if the output includes multiple rows, and hence more than one primary key value (which it would have to do unless there is only one row)? As mentioned, this sounds like you're trying to solve a different problem. You should describe _that_ problem, not the way you think you should fix it.

Comment: @ThomA I have updated the question with the actual goal. Hopefully it make sense why I am trying to do that

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have updated the question to include the original problem and the way I have thought to fix it. You are right there are multiple rows. It would not work the way I have thought. I have included the original problem though and I will really appreciate if you can suggest something

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired output? A query that doesn't work doesn't really help. :-) Also, why do you want a _different_ `json_query` for each of a hard-coded list of employees? This doesn't seem very relational.

Comment: Are you attempting to build a hierarchy in the JSON? - is that the intent? It would be more conventional to simply include a "parent"  attribute/value I think. & Probably a whole lot easier to achieve.